# Autofill Cell Range with formulas. Fills up instead of down

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have formulas located in cell Range B6:AH6. I want to fill the columns beginning on B7 with the same formulas. The range is dynamic so I created a function to find the last row.

My procedure to autofill is not working properly. I did some online research and put a code together. However, when I run the procedure it fills up instead of down. How can I get it to fill down.

Here is the procedure I worked out:

First the Function to find the last row:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal rngToCheck As Excel.Range) As Long

Dim rngLast As Excel.Range

rngLast = rngToCheck.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious)

    If rngLast Is Nothing Then
        GetLastRow = rngToCheck.Rows.Count
    Else
        GetLastRow = rngLast.Rows.Count
    End If

End Function
```

This is my procedure to autofill the range:

```
    Dim eeRefSheets As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim cellRange As Excel.Range

    For i As Long = 1 To 3 Step 1

        eeRefSheets = EmployeeSheets(i)

        With eeRefSheets
            cellRange = .Range("B6:H6")

            Dim lngLr As Long = GetLastRow(.Cells)

            cellRange.AutoFill(.Range("B6:H" & lngLr), Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault)

        End With

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts Yes B6:H6 is correct. I just saw my error on the posting, I fixed the error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. My function to find the last row was incorrect. Fixed the issue and the data filled the cells.

```
    Dim eeRefSheets As Excel.Worksheet

For i As Long = 1 To 3 Step 1

    eeRefSheets = EmployeeSheets(i)

    With eeRefSheets
        Dim lngLr As Long

        lngLr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows).Row

        .Range("B6:AH6").AutoFill(.Range("B6:AH" & lngLr), Excel.XlAutoFillType.xlFillDefault)

    End With

Next i
```

End Sub